# Ruby process running at max CPU usage and not serving any page - Ubuntu Nginx Unicorn Rails Configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, nginx, unicorn

I am following this guide to setup Rails service using Nginx and Unicorn http://ariejan.net/2011/09/14/lighting-fast-zero-downtime-deployments-with-git-capistrano-nginx-and-unicorn/

When I started Nginx without Unicorn I get 502 Bad Gateway error
and as soon as I start the Unicorn server using the following command `unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -D` the request times out and I get 504 Gateway Time-out error. The CPU usage for ruby process is 100% and seems like something is stuck in a loop but I do not understand what is happening

nginx/1.2.6 (Ubuntu)

This is my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user ubuntu staff;

# Change this depending on your hardware
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay off;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_min_length 500;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml applicat
ion/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

and this is my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
upstream home {
  # fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
  # to return a good HTTP response (in case the Unicorn master nukes a
  # single worker for timing out).

  # for UNIX domain socket setups:
  server unix:/tmp/home.socket fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    # if you're running multiple servers, instead of "default" you should
    # put your main domain name here
    listen 80;

    # you could put a list of other domain names this application answers
    server_name patellabs.com;

    root /home/ubuntu/apps/home/current/public;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/home_access.log;
    rewrite_log on;

    location / {
        #all requests are sent to the UNIX socket
        proxy_pass  http://home;
        proxy_redirect     off;

        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        client_max_body_size       10m;
        client_body_buffer_size    128k;

        proxy_connect_timeout      90;
        proxy_send_timeout         90;
        proxy_read_timeout         90;

        proxy_buffer_size          4k;
        proxy_buffers              4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    }

    # if the request is for a static resource, nginx should serve it directly
    # and add a far future expires header to it, making the browser
    # cache the resource and navigate faster over the website
    # this probably needs some work with Rails 3.1's asset pipe_line
    location ~ ^/(images|javascripts|stylesheets|system)/  {
      root /home/ubuntu/apps/home/current/public;
      expires max;
      break;
    }
}
```

Comment: does it do that only in a certain controller/action ? or all the time ?

Comment: It doing it even when requesting static pages like index.html that is in the public folder. The Ruby process is 100% without me even going to the controller

Comment: did you check the error_log, or running it locally and check the server log ?, i don't believe this has any thing to do with nginx it self.

Comment: Is the log file here? /var/log/nginx/home_access.log

Comment: I meant more the rails log, should be in your rails `project-path/log/production.log` or something like that